# Como criar um CardView igual ao Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Bom dia,
Estou querendo criar um layout igual ao da Google Play, porém não estou sabendo como fazer o design. Poderia me ajudar?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW2wT.jpg

Link do código XML 
https://pastebin.com/sNytLsNz

Comment: Igual em que sentido?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O  problema é que você não definiu um `child` principal para o **cardview**. Essa child, que será um `viewgroup` vai organizar todas as outras views dentro do cardview chegando ao resultado que você quer.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/cardview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="50dp">

       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/ads_title"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
                     android:text="Melhores preços" />

                 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_ads"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                        android:scrollbars="none" />

       </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema!